# Como cerrar mi aplicación de windows forms al terminar un proceso?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

espero me puedan ayudar, estoy trabando de que mi aplicación se cierre de manera automática cuando acaba de realizar todo un proceso de insertado de datos, lo estoy tratando de hacer con `Application.Exit();` pero no funciona.
Este es mi último proceso que realiza mi desarrollo y ahi es donde colocó `Application.Exit();` y no funciona [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como se queda mi ventana. Espero me puedan apoyar si estoy mandando a llamar mal la instrucción o me falta algo de implementar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Investigando vi que existe la instrucción `Environment.Exit(1);`, la cual la utilice y me funciono muy bien.

Comment: Un apunte el número que metes en el paréntesis indica un error para marcar que salió todo bien es el número 0, el 1 significa que un fichero requerido no está presente